# Ember way to implement Contact us form

Tags: ember.js

I've a website implemented using emberJS, It has a "contact us" page, now when someone fills up the form & submit the data I need to do implement a POST request. Do I need to create a model for this ? right now I just did `$.post(...)`.

I just wanted to know is there any much cleaner(or may I say emberish way) to implement this ?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, a `ContactRequest` model seems like the most idiomatic way to go about this. That way you can use the regular Ember facilities and later add features like a backend that shows pending contact requests and - depending on your use case - does things like sorting them by subject area etc.